# Spring Boot Ajax request hibernate validation message not resolve, instead return default message

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, hibernate

I have search a lot on internet but failed to get answer. I have a requirement where some form need to open in popup and validation should be done.

Validation working properly, but failed to resolve message resource correspond to

> validationMessages.properties

file. When i open that form in stand alone tab then message displaying correctly, but failed when doing ajax request.

Kindly suggest me what to do.

Comment: what is the response of your ajax call? I think it might be a client side issue

Comment: response contains hibernate default message and key. I want my define custom message will be show. If i try to get the resource then resource working fine.